# Origine del termine gagà

Tags: etymology

Il termine ***[gagà](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=gag%C3%A0)***, poco usato recentemente, si riferisce a:

> - uomo vanesio che ostenta eleganza e raffinatezza.

Ho letto recentemente su una rivista che il termine ha origini napoletane ma non sono riuscito a trovare conferma di questo:

> - ***Etimologia***: ← voce onom., diffusa dai giornali umoristici dopo la prima guerra mondiale; cfr. il fr. gaga ‘vecchio rimbambito’.

(Dizionario Garzanti)

Qualcuno ha maggiori informazioni a riguardo? Il termine ha veramente origini napoletane?

Comment: Ma, secondo il Garzanti, proviene dal francese, non dal napoletano.

Comment: In realtà  dice: confronta il francese "gaga" che significa "vecchio rimbambito". Per cui il termine potrebbe essere quello francese che in Italia ha poi assunto un significato diverso. Come? Dove? Quando?

Comment: So che queste domande sono impopolari... ma ci provo lo stesso.

Comment: @Gio Io la trovo una domanda molto interessante. Anzi, dovremmo averne di più di domande così.

Comment: Se può servire a formare una risposta insieme ad altro materiale: il dizionario etimologico di Battisti-Alessio dice: «dal fr. *gaga* sciocco, caduto da piccolo, da una radice onomatopeica *gag-* (*kak-*) balbettare, cfr. spagn. e port. *gago* sordomuto».

Comment: Su questo sito (non si riferisce ad un dizionario ma una sartoria) http://www.sartoriagaga.com/gaga.html si fa riferimento al gagà napoletano di inizio del secolo scorso. Potrebbe essere un indizio

Comment: Sono napoletano, e ricordo i miei genitori e nonni utilizzare il termine. È probabile che venga dal francese, e che sia stato adottato nel dialetto napoletano, durante il periodo di dominazione francese.

Answer (score 4):

Gagà è infatti una parola francese, come attestato da diversi vocabolari, ad esempio questo:

[Gagà su vocabolario Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-italien/gaga/32594)

dove viene dato il significato di "rimbambito", e l'etimologia onomatopeica ("ga-ga" imita i vocalizzi di un infante, e per traslato di un rimbambito).

Sono napoletano, e ricordo i miei genitori e nonni utilizzare il termine. È probabile che il termine sia stato adottato nel dialetto napoletano durante il periodo di dominazione francese.
È possibile trovare diversi riferimenti documentati, sopratutto in campo musicale, ecco alcuni esempi:

["Il gagà e la sciantosa" interpretata dai fratelli Maggio;](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZrwAgGBfkU)

[Vittorio Marsiglia interpreta la macchietta intitolata "Gagà";](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AouTeHVwIQE)

[riferimento al termine gagà, in cui se ne spiega il significato.](http://www.stefanoserino.com/it/brevi-saggi-stefano-serino/56-la-macchietta-armando-gill-stefano-serino.html)

Answer (score -1):

Potrebbe derivare dall'irlandese "gaige", che per l'appunto significa dandy, elegantone. È probabile che sia stato mutuato da parte di comunità italo-americane da immigrati irlandesi negli Stati Uniti, e poi da lì sia "rientrato" in Italia. Ma questa è tutta una mia ipotesi, basata comunque sull'identità perfetta di significato e quasi perfetta di pronuncia. In ogni caso, in nessun'altra lingua, a parte queste due, ha il significato di damerino. Quindi...

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Quindi...? “The English word dog and the Mbabaram word dog have exactly the same meaning, but by complete coincidence”, e c'è un ampio elenco di simili coincidenze (cioè parole con lo stesso significato e un suono molto simile che però _non_ si sono influenzate a vicenda) nella voce [“False cognate”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate) della Wikipedia inglese, tra cui per esempio _feu_ in francese e _Feuer_ in tedesco, o _much_ in inglese e _mucho_ in spagnolo.